# TFS 2015 PowerShell edit file

Tags: powershell, tfs

Is it possible to check out a file from TFS 2015 with PowerShell, then replace a line in the file and check it in again?

If yes, can you please give a hint how to start this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to simply call `tf.exe` from your powershell and have it check in the file after changing it.

```
& tf vc checkout filename.ext
# edit the file using powershell
& tf vc checkin filename.ext
```

Or you can invoke the TFS API objects like I'm doing in the VSTS TFVC Extension, which uses powershell to check in files as part of the build process. It does require quite a bit of code to make it work in all situations. Since it's all open sourced, you can find it here:

https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-tfvc-tasks/blob/master/vsts-tfvc-checkin/TfvcCheckin.ps1

Comment: Thanks! Was able to solve the issue with your hints!